# How do I do Cucumber-style acceptance testing of an Ember app?

Tags: cucumber, ember.js, jasmine

Currently I am doing acceptance testing of my web applications using Cucumber and webrat. I realise that I can use Cucumber and selenium, but is there a better, perhaps pure JavaScript way to do it? (I currently use Jasmine and RSpec for my unit and integration tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [Cucumber.js](http://git.io/cukejs). It's the official JavaScript port of Cucumber.

Comment: I've been playing with Cucumber.js, which seems to work nicely in concert with vowsjs for unit testing.

Comment: Jasmine is also a very nice alternative, regarding "unit testing".

Answer (score 1):

I am using cucumber with selenium. It works but it's slow. In general, if you are still using webrat then I'd suggest that you should use capybara instead (it has basically replaced webrat for most developers). There are several drivers available for capybara. Selenium is one of them. There are, however, a couple of better options in terms of performance.

There is capybara-webkit which uses a headless webkit browser: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit

There is also a new driver by Jon Leighton called poltergeist: https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist It is based on the Phantoms JS.

It's worth looking in to both of these options. The main issues I have run in to is that sometimes there are parts of my apps that work fine with the selenium driver but not on these headless options and it's very difficult to debug because the javascript console is not exposed by these drivers. But the performance increase versus selenium may make extended debugging worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'll take a look at those suggestions.

Comment: between the two my recent experience has found capybara-webkit to be easier to debug... poltergeist was giving me errors like "undefined is not a function" with no context...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using capybara and selenium. But it' doesn't play well with binding. I always got a failure because my values are not binded while I run my cucumber features.